# Latin/Greek morpheme meaning 'fundamental'?

Tags: latin, greek, affixes, morphemes

Is there a Latin or Greek prefix or suffix out there that can be added to a word to make it mean the fundamental from which everything is derived?

Here's an example. You've got linguistics, that is made up of the fundamental branches like morphology and syntax. But then you have phraseology, also a branch of linguistics. Both morphology and phraseology are branches within linguistics, but you wouldn't place them equally. That's because morphology is a fundamental branch of linguistics, and phraseology is a sub-branch of semantics, which **is** a fundamental branch.

So basically, I'm looking for a prefix/suffix that could be added to the word "branch" (or any other word) to distinguish it from the sub-branches (or what is derived from the fundamental). I feel like I've heard/read the use of such a morpheme but I can't remember.

Comment: I think "ur" as a prefix is pretty close to what you're asking for.

Comment: @user888379 Interesting that you'd mention that prefix (that I hadn't heard of). In Norwegian, which is my mother tongue, "ur" is an adjective that means "old" or "ancient", and a noun that means "clock" or "watch". Just like there is "urlanguage", Norwegian has the word "urspråk".

Comment: But I doubt "ur" is Greek of Latin.

Comment: Ur- is indeed German (Dutch: oer-).

Comment: Oops, I sort of glossed over the "Latin or Greek" stipulation...

Comment: Try _proto-_; it's Greek and means 'first', or even 'before first', like Proto-Indo-European.